# How do I install the R package rgl on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: r, rgl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem Installing rgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473067/problem-installing-rgl)

I'm trying to install the R package rgl on Ubuntu 9.10.  I'm using R version 2.12.1.

I got the following error: "configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h"

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473067/problem-installing-rgl) earlier without the restriction that I use Ubuntu 9.10, and the answer I got was to update R, but I haven't been able to do this, possibly because Ubuntu 9.10 is not supported by the folks at CRAN.

Comment: Do you have OpenGL (http://www.opengl.org/) installed?

Comment: @JackManey I don't know.  How would I tell?

Comment: How about updating your Ubuntu? It's a couple of years out of date and not an LTS release (I think).

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-if-package-is-installed-in-linux/#debian

Comment: @JackManey How is that helpful?  I didn't get an answer to that question because it wasn't clear that I wanted to do this on Ubuntu 9.10 in the question.  This question is looking like it might get me somewhere.

Comment: No, I don't have OpenGL installed.  I have not been successful in figuring out how to install it.

Comment: @Name:  It's helpful to the community because we wish to avoid duplicate questions when possible (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/).  As to how to install OpenGL, download the source, and run `configure`, `make`, and `sudo make install`.

Comment: Also, "Name" this site works with a reputation syste, which you can use to your advantage by participating according to its rules. Re-posting from anonymous one-off accounts is not the way to do that.

Comment: Jack, no, he is on Ubunto so  you do **not** recommend rebuilding OpenGL from source but rather by installing the appropriate existing packages; see my answer.

Comment: Ok, I didn't mean to upset the community.  I guess my point though is that my first question didn't get answered, which I believe is because I wasn't clear that the Linux version I was using was important to the question.  If you remove this question, how will this ever get answered?  I realize now that I should have posted this question originally, but if I edit the old question, then people's comments and answers won't make sense, and I would expect that no one new would look at it.  How is this sort of situation handled?

Comment: From the OpenGL website, I found a [FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#Where_can_I_download.3F) that tells me that OpenGL is not a software product, it is a specification, and that I probably need to download drivers.  The next question gives instructions on how to do that, but I do not understand them.

Comment: What don't you understand?  What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It looks like I need to update my graphics drivers, but this does not sound like the same thing as downloading the source, running configure, etc.  I started searching for instructions on how to update my graphics drivers, but I was not able to find anything that would allow me to do that quickly, and since it's not clear that this is going to be helpful (since it's not what either commenter on here recommended) and it would take me a long time, I decided to ask for help again.  I also spent a while searching for somewhere to download the OpenGL source from, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 9):

Just do

```
  sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl
```

As there is a reason we spent time harder-to-install packages with less common dependencies.  So that you do not have to worry.

If you insist on building it locally, you can still take advantage of the package for understanding its Build-Dependencies, i.e. `apt-get build-dep r-cran-rgl`.  For the current package (on Ubuntu 11.04) I have

```
 Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.0), r-base-dev (>= 2.12.1), cdbs, \
        libgl1-mesa-dev | libgl-dev, \
        libglu1-mesa-dev | libglu-dev, \
        libpng12-dev, libx11-dev, libxt-dev, x11proto-core-dev
```

Comment: I did that, and it said "r-cran-rgl is already the newest version."  But when I go into R and type "library(rgl)", it says "Error in library(rgl) : there is no package called 'rgl'".

Comment: Then look at the output of `.libPath()` and compare it with what you have installed.

Comment: I guess I should mention that I am not a competent Linux user...How do I look at the output of .libPath()?  I typed that in to my terminal, and it didn't give me anything, and I couldn't find anything online about it.  I also don't know how I would compare it with what I have installed.

Comment: @Name you type that within R. It is an R function that returns the list of current libraries and their paths.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Ah! Unfortunately though it says "Error: could not find function ".libPath""

Comment: @Name That's because it is `.libPaths()` with an `s`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Ok, that worked.  What do you think Dirk meant for me to compare the output to?

Comment: @Name I don't use Ubuntu, but check that the place it installed the package when you did `apt get ....` is the same as, or one of, the entries shown by `.libPaths()`. It might not have put the package where your R is looking for it.

Comment: @GavinSimpson "/usr/lib/R/site-library" is in the output of .libPaths() and the output of "dpkg -L r-cran-rgl".  There's quite a bit more that is output by "dpkg -L r-cran-rgl" though.

Comment: @Name Sorry I can't help further - I don't use Ubuntu and compile my own R on Linux so am not going to be much help I'm afraid. Take this up on the [R Ubuntu list](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) if Dirk doesn't comment further.

Comment: I would try `i1 <- installed.packages(); i1["rgl",]` which will give you a version number and a `LibPath` (i.e. the location where it is installed).  `.libPaths()` will tell you all the locations where R will look for installed packages. On the other hand, I'm not sure (not being a Debian/`apt-get` whiz) how to ask `apt` where it is putting the stuff from `r-cran-rgl` ...

Comment: Ben, that last part is eg `dpkg -l r-cran-rgl`.  Good advice otherwise.

Comment: @Ben > i1 <- installed.packages(); i1["rgl",]
Error: subscript out of bounds

Comment: @Dirk $ dpkg -l r-cran-rgl
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
    | Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
    |/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

Comment: Sorry, my typo, use uppercase L: "dpkg -L r-cran-rgl"