# iGraph or some other Lib to Draw Torus with symbol -markings?

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I need to draw this torus [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124198/5902) (where you connect the horizontal and vertical sides to get the 3D object. The iGraph package has at least random geometric graphs something, more [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/igraph.pdf), but apparently not for drawing this kind of detailed torus below.

[image]

**R: a bit torus-looking but without labels and decorations etc**

```
d <- 1e6
R <- 9
r <- 2
a <- 0:(d*pi)/30
b <- 0:(d*pi)/40
plot3d(x = (R + r*cos(a)) * cos(b),
       y = (R + r*cos(a)) * sin(b),
       z = r * sin(a))
```

**Perhaps related**

3. [How do I install the R package rgl on Ubuntu 9.10, using R version 2.12.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473067/how-do-i-install-the-r-package-rgl-on-ubuntu-9-10-using-r-version-2-12-1)

<sub>**Some examples with High-end Software for inspiration**</sub>

2. Mathematica demo [here](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/MATLAB/6thEdition/torus.m), [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNJYiQucLtA), WA demo [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/surfaces/torus/1r/yh/07/) --.
3. Maple demo [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plottools/torus), --.

Comment: Your R code generates a random graph (using the distance on a torus), and then arranges the nodes to plot the graph on the plane. You probably do not want a random graph, and you probably do not want the nodes to be rearranged to make the graph as planar as possible. If you want 3D plots, you can check the `Rgl` package: that should be close to what Maple/Mathematica do.